# Fonts not rendering initially inside HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, html5-canvas, base64

I have a problem where custom fonts inside HTML canvas do not initially render (they do load when I refresh the page). Below is how they look on mobile:

### [image]

After doing some research I've tried the following solutions:

1. Forcing render by adding HTML at top of page, e.g. `<div style="font-family:'gotham-black'"></div>`
2. Convert fonts to base64 so loaded into CSS
3. Add setTimeout in JS for when Canvas is initialised.

None of these solutions work. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?